# Quartz fails if it has a parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, quartz.net

There is a Consolle application in which I created the SmsSenderJob class that implements IJob, I want to transfer the IPiggyBankSer service in the SmsSenderJob constructor, but it doesn't work. when I add a constructor, the Execute method is not executed.

```
internal class SmsSenderJob : IJob
{
    private readonly double amount = 5;
    private IServiceProvider _provider;
    private IPiggyBankSer _piggy;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public SmsSenderJob(IJobExecutionContext context, IPiggyBankSer piggy)
    {
        _piggy = piggy;
        _logger = (ILogger)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("logger");
        _provider = (IServiceProvider)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("provider");
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
           Console.Writline("Hello");
    }
```

Comment: Have you any errors?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad No

Comment: Can you show please how you are calling Execute.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the following will help to resolve this kind of issues:

- [enable logging](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#adding-logging), Quartz will tell what is happening
- make sure you have configured [MS DI support](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) (you haven't stated what DI solution you are using though)
- check out [the example ASP.NET Core application on GitHub](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/main/src/Quartz.Examples.AspNetCore), it shows all things in action

Generally when asking questions it helps when you supply more context like whether you are using .NET Framework or .NET Core, which version of Quartz and what other libraries are involved, like MS DI or something other.